# left_join in a for loop with different columns names

Tags: r, for-loop, left-join, cran

I have a data.frame called `a` whose structure is similar to:-

```
a <- data.frame(X1=c("A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "D"),
                X2=c("B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "A"),
                X3=c("C", "D", "A", "B", "A", "B")
               )
```

And I have another set which is:-

```
b <- data.frame(Xn=c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                Feature=c("some", "more", "what", "why"))
```

I want to add all the `Features` from set `b` to set `a`, such that `X1`, `X2` and `X3` have their corresponding feature column in set `a`. In other words, the columns in set `a` become:-

```
colnames(a) <- c("X1", "X2", "X3", "Features1", "Features2", "Features3")
```

How can I do this using a left_join in a for loop??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, we can `unlist` `a` dataframe and `match` it with `b$Xn` to get corresponding `Feature` value. We can `cbind` this dataframe to original dataframe to get final answer.

```
temp <- a
temp[] <- b$Feature[match(unlist(temp), b$Xn)]
names(temp) <- paste0('Feature', seq_along(temp))
cbind(a, temp)

#  X1 X2 X3 Feature1 Feature2 Feature3
#1  A  B  C     some     more     what
#2  B  C  D     more     what      why
#3  C  D  A     what      why     some
#4  A  A  B     some     some     more
#5  C  B  A     what     more     some
#6  D  A  B      why     some     more
```

---

In `tidyverse`, we can get the data in long format, join the data and get it back to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

a %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row) %>%
  left_join(b, by = c('value' = 'Xn'))  %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = Feature) %>%
  select(-row) %>%
  rename_all(~paste0('Feature', seq_along(.))) %>%
  bind_cols(a, .)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using `mutate_all` to `recode` all of the columns in `a`:

```
library(tidyverse)

a %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(feat=recode(., !!!set_names(as.character(b$Feature), b$Xn))))
```

> ```
>   X1    X2    X3    X1_feat X2_feat X3_feat
> 1 A     B     C     some    more    what   
> 2 B     C     D     more    what    why    
> 3 C     D     A     what    why     some   
> 4 A     A     B     some    some    more   
> 5 C     B     A     what    more    some   
> 6 D     A     B     why     some    more
> ```

You can add a `rename_at` to get the desired names:

```
a %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(f=recode(., !!!set_names(as.character(b$Feature), b$Xn)))) %>% 
  rename_at(vars(matches("f")), ~gsub(".([0-9]).*", "Feature\\1", .))
```

> ```
>   X1 X2 X3 Feature1 Feature2 Feature3
> 1  A  B  C     some     more     what
> 2  B  C  D     more     what      why
> 3  C  D  A     what      why     some
> 4  A  A  B     some     some     more
> 5  C  B  A     what     more     some
> 6  D  A  B      why     some     more
> ```